# Change value in array of objects on dropdown unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, dropdown

I want to change the values in my array of objects based on select from the dropdown.

```
arr= [
        {name: 'one', in_order: true, other_key:'ga'},
        {name: 'one', in_order: true, other_key:'gb'},
        {name: 'one', in_order: true, other_key:'gc'},
        {name: 'two', in_order: false, other_key:'gd'},
        {name: 'two', in_order: false, other_key:'ge'},
        {name: 'two', in_order: false, other_key:'gf'},
        {name: 'three', in_order: false, other_key:'gg'},
        {name: 'three', in_order: false, other_key:'gh'},
        {name: 'three', in_order: false, other_key:'gi'},
        {name: 'four', in_order: false, other_key:'gj'},
        {name: 'four', in_order: false, other_key:'gk'},
        {name: 'four', in_order: false, other_key:'gl'}
     ]
```

I did this:

```
$(`#filter`).on('change', function() {
   yo = [];
   $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
        yo.push(this.value);
   });

  arr.forEach(arr_opts => {
            yo.forEach(opt => {
                if (arr_opts.name == opt) {
                    arr_opts.in_order = true;
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(arr);
});
```

WHen I do this, I get my result. But when I unselect the result in the dropdown, it does not change back to false. For example, if I check `one` and `two`. It changes the in value to `true` for both in the array. But if I then unselect `two`, `two` remains as `true`.

On unselect, can I change the value of the selected back to `false`?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noob0605/5am04ct3/3/)

Comment: You have multiple objects that have the same name.

Comment: I need to change the `in_order` for all in the object. There are other key-value pairs in that object

Comment: How are you targeting the array values though? You'd need to know the specific index in order to modify it, no? Or are you just wanting to change the last one, and then make all others false? It's that piece of logic that is unclear.

Comment: I am targeting them by name in the array. The dropdown values match the name in the array. So every time I make a selection/unselect in the dropdown, it changes the `in_order` value

Comment: What are the names? Cause you have three that have the same name 'one' in this example.

Comment: Yes, I know, so if I select `one` in my dropdown, I want all the `arr.in_order` to change to `true`. If I unselect it, I want it to change to `false`. My dropdown just has 4 values, `one, two, three, four`.

Comment: I edited the array, there are supposed to be more keys in there

Comment: @JoelHager, I have added a fiddle

Comment: So what you're trying to do is any change event on this form, you want *any* value in `arr` that matches *any* of the selected items to be `in_order: true` and *any* other that aren't to be set to false, yes?

Comment: I'm *sure* there's a more efficient solution to this, but I got it fixed using some forEach loops. Since there's not many options, it's not too big of a performance impact. https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/go5p2vne/44/

Comment: I was just going to post the answer. I got it to work using `$.inArray`

Comment: Ah. I'm unfamiliar with doing that in jQuery. I'll have to look it up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out using `$.inArray`

```js
arr= [
        {name: 'one', in_order: true, other_key:'ga'},
        {name: 'one', in_order: true, other_key:'gb'},
        {name: 'one', in_order: true, other_key:'gc'},
        {name: 'two', in_order: false, other_key:'gd'},
        {name: 'two', in_order: false, other_key:'ge'},
        {name: 'two', in_order: false, other_key:'gf'},
        {name: 'three', in_order: false, other_key:'gg'},
        {name: 'three', in_order: false, other_key:'gh'},
        {name: 'three', in_order: false, other_key:'gi'},
        {name: 'four', in_order: false, other_key:'gj'},
        {name: 'four', in_order: false, other_key:'gk'},
        {name: 'four', in_order: false, other_key:'gl'}
     ]
console.log(arr);

let yo;
$(`#filter`).on('change', function() {
   yo = [];
   $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
        yo.push(this.value);
   });
   
 console.log(yo);

  arr.forEach(arr_opts => {
   if ($.inArray(arr_opts.name, yo) !== -1) {
     arr_opts.in_order = true;
   } else {
     arr_opts.in_order = false;
    }
  });
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='filter' multiple>
  <option value='one' selected>one</option>
  <option value='two'>two</option>
  <option value='three'>three</option>
  <option value='four'>four</option>
</select>
```